# Windows 10 Mobile - App crashes when selecting from the gallery

Tags: windows, cordova, ionic2, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

So I have used [cordova-plugin-camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) in my project to make photos and select from the gallery.

My android- and iOS app does not have any problems at all. But when testing it out on a live Windows 10 Mobile device, my app crashes after I selected an image from my gallery.

The camera does work though.

The code I use (simplified)

```
this.camera.getPicture({
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: false,           //gave problems in Windows
  correctOrientation: true
}).then(imageURI => {
  this.navCtrl.push(Page2, {image: imageURI});
}, err => {
  // ionic alert, way of still showing alerts to Windows users
  this.alertCtrl.create({message: err}).present();
});
```

And in the Page2 component I have, before anything gets executed, an alert that would normally show the imageURI passed.

Neither the success nor the error callback is executed, the app just shuts down.

I tried adding a try-catch around it but it seems like it doesn't throw an error. (at least, the catch doesn't catch it.)

Comment: Did you check this ? https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#windows-quirks

Comment: @suraj yes, and that is for WP8 and WP8.1. I have found out what was causing it and will write an answer on it later today. Different problem although the workaround needed for Windows Universal is the same as WP8(.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in Windows Universal Application, you can't access the photo-library when building a Cordova application (at least, I haven't yet found how). Because of read-/write-access on files. (Imagine opening a windows 10 app on your desktop and it just having all your photo's lined up for you, wouldn't be a great idea).

A workaround is to use a file-input and triggering it on a button click (so your UI doesn't change). This way the user gets to pick the file for him/her/itself and provides the app with read-/write access to that file.

The html would look a bit like this:

```
<input type="file" hidden #file (change)="fileChanged()"></input>
<button (click)="file.click()">My custom button</button>
```

And to read the src (as dataURI) from the fileinput:

```
fileChange(event) {
    // show loading screen, this is not very fast on UWP
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Processing photo...'
    });
    loading.present();

    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if(fileList.length > 0) {
      let file: File = fileList[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();

      // define callback seperate from onload, else e.target.result is undefined
      let callback = (e) => { 
         loading.dismiss(); 
         let src = e.target.result;
      };

      reader.onload = callback;

      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }
  }
```